# Getting 18 years before date from calender

Tags: java, datetime, datepicker

I need to get complete date(dd/mm/yyyy) which is 18 years from now. i used code as
Calendar calc = Calendar.getInstance(); calc.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18); which retrives 18 years before year not month or date. I need one day 18 years before current date even in corner cases like 1st of any month also. Example 1-06-2015 is current date should get 31-05-1997.To be noted i need code in java6

Comment: `calc = Calendar.getInstance();` `calc.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);` `calc.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);` `Date date = calc.getTime();` `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date)");`

Comment: If at all possible, you should be take advantage of either Java 8's new Time API or Joda-Time, they are generally easier and less messy then `Calendar`

Comment: @MadProgrammer the above code will work but in corner cases like 1st of the month this will not work

Comment: Should do, do you have an example where it doesn't

Comment: In birthdate age confirmation. i need to register user above 18 years of age.

Comment: Yes, and my testing (of the code in the comment) works just fine, even for `01/06/2015`, it returns `31/05/1997` just fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java, a date value is just the number of milliseconds from some fixed point in time, the related classes don't carry a format of their own which you can change, this is what date/time formatters are for

## Calendar

From your example, you're basically ignoring the fact that changing any of the `Calendar`'s fields, will effect all the others, for example...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2015, Calendar.JUNE, 01); // Comment this out for today...
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
Date date = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date));
```

Which outputs

```
31/05/1997
```

I would, however, recommend using either Java 8's new Time API or Joda-Time

## Java 8 Time API

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
ld = ld.minusYears(18).minusDays(1);
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").format(ld));
```

Which outputs

```
26/06/1997
```

### Edge case...

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JUNE, 1);
ld = ld.minusYears(18).minusDays(1);
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").format(ld));
```

Which outputs

```
31/05/1997
```

## JodaTime

```
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate();
ld = ld.minusYears(18).minusDays(1);
System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").print(ld));
```

Which outputs

```
26/06/1997
```

### Edge case...

```
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(2015, DateTimeConstants.JUNE, 1);
ld = ld.minusYears(18).minusDays(1);
System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").print(ld));
```

Which outputs

```
31/05/1997
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html), as it will make date manipulation and math very easy.  For example:

```
DateTime futureDate = new DateTime();
futureDate.minusYears(18).minusDays(1);
futureDate.toDate(); // return a regular Date object
```

Comment: It's -18 Years, -1 day, but right idea. Add a Java 8 Time example, earn a up-vote (picky ain't I).  You might also like to highlight what the OP's doing wrong at the moment as well ;)

Comment: @MUHAMMEDSHAMEER Then use JodaTime.  Besides, other people who might have this problem may be lucky enough to have Java 8

Comment: Joda Time only requires JDK 1.5+ for v.2.0 as noted [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/upgradeto200.html) as MadProgrammer shows us below... it's the clear winner on ease of use.

Comment: We are using java 6 not java 8 so we cannot use joda 8

Comment: Joda is still 2.x, and as I stated usable by java 6