# How to format datetime in utc to local time format?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a datetime object whose value is in format (got thru breakpoint)

```
dateTime = 2015-09-04T08:37:00.440-07:00
```

I am trying get corresponding local time.

I used format `"EEEE, MMM d 'at' hh:mm a"`.

```
dateTime.toString(format);
```

But it does not take -07:00 hours offset into account and gives back:

```
Friday, Sep 4 at 08:37 AM
```

Expected Value:     `Friday, Sep 4 at 01:37 AM`

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using a `DateTimeFormatter`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085927/getting-18-years-before-date-from-calender/31086127#31086127)

Comment: I solved it by creating datetime with DateTime(java.util.date)...that works for me for now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask to convert to the local (default) timezone by calling `withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())`.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse("2015-09-04T08:37:00.440-07:00");
System.out.println(dateTime);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString("EEEE, MMM d 'at' hh:mm a"));

dateTime = dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.println(dateTime);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString("EEEE, MMM d 'at' hh:mm a"));

dateTime = dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(dateTime);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString("EEEE, MMM d 'at' hh:mm a"));
```

*Output*

```
2015-09-04T08:37:00.440-07:00
Friday, Sep 4 at 08:37 AM

2015-09-04T11:37:00.440-04:00
Friday, Sep 4 at 11:37 AM

2015-09-04T15:37:00.440Z
Friday, Sep 4 at 03:37 PM
```

Comment: thank you for the response....however, this is not the expected o/p...I want to print the string with -07:00 applied before output...Friday, Sep 4 at 01:37 AM instead of Friday, Sep 4 at 08:37 AM...

Comment: You are misunderstanding the meaning of -07:00. It specifies that the date/time is for a location in a timezone that is 7 hours behind GMT/UTC. If you want the time in UTC, you **add** 7 hours and get `15:37`. If you are *in* the timezone of `-07:00` (which is PDT as an example), the time is in *your* timezone. As you can see, I'm on the east coast (EDT), so my timezone is `-04:00` and the time is `11:37 AM`, which is 3 hours *higher*.

Comment: It is now `10:37 PM` here (EDT) and `DateTime.now()` returns `2015-09-02T22:37:01.134-04:00`. My time, my timezone.