# How to check whether a date is more than 30 days old?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have a `java.util.Date` which I need to check whether it is more than 30 days. What is the best way to check that out?

```
for(Date date: listOfDates) {
  // how to check this date to see whether it is more than 30 days limit
  if(checkDateLimit()) {

  }
}
```

I am on Java 7.

Comment: You could use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085927/getting-18-years-before-date-from-calender/31086127#31086127) to calculate a date 30 days in the past then determine if the specified date is before or after it

Comment: getTime() will help you compare the date with little calculation.

Comment: @david Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how formal you want to be about the definition of "30 days." If all you want to know is whether the given date (which, in Java, includes time down to the millisecond) is 30 days (to the millisecond) old, then you can calculate how many milliseconds there are in 30 days and see if the current date is more than that number of milliseconds larger than the given date.

Dates reveal their millisecond values through getTime().

```
private boolean olderThan30Days(Date givenDate)
{
  long currentMillis = new Date().getTime();
  long millisIn30Days = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  boolean result = givenDate.getTime() < (currentMillis - millisIn30Days);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: oops. thanks. edited.

Comment: BTW, My date format is like this `Thu Jun 02 12:43:44 PDT 2016`. And I don't see this method `getTimeInMillis()`?

Comment: You could use Java 8s Date/Time API or JodaTime which can calculate the difference between two points in days

Comment: I am still on Java 7 and cannot switch to Java 8 yet.

Comment: @david Then use JodaTime or Calendar, use the current date, subtract 30 days from it then use before or after (methods on Date/Calendar) to compare the values, it overcomes some of the major issues with direct manipulation

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you add an answer of using with JodaTime. That will help me understand better on how to use it.

Comment: I would use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `new Date().getTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: Also, I think you mean `getTime()`.

Comment: (sigh) getTime() is the correct method. Edited again. I think introducing Jodatime or Java 8 APIs just confuses things.

Comment: And date/time manipulation is error prone, cumbersome, frought with issues and generally discouraged

Comment: By all means, if subtracting one long from another and comparing the result to a third confuses you, then introduce a new library to do it.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use Java 8, you can do:

```
boolean checkDateLimit(Date date) {
    // convert Date into Java 8 LocalDate
    LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // count number of days between the given date and today
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(localDate, today);
    return days > 30;
}
```

Comment: Still on Java 7. :(

Comment: @david Use JodaTime then, it's very similar

Comment: Right, the Java 8 Date/Time API is pretty much based on JodaTime, so if you can use JodaTime the result should be very similar.

Comment: @earangol can you provide an example with JodaTime if possible?

Answer (score 3):

As recommended by others, you should use JodaTime:

```
  private static boolean olderThan30Days(Date givenDate) {
    boolean result =
        Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(givenDate), new DateTime()).isGreaterThan(Days.days(30));
    return result;
  }
```